# How to access NHibernate.IQueryOver<T,T> within ActiveRecord?

Tags: castle-activerecord, queryover

I use DetachedCriteria primarily, it has a static method For to construct an instance. But it seems IQueryOver is more favourable, I want to use it.
The normal way to get an instance of IQueryOver is Isession.Query, and I want get it with ActiveRecord gracefully, anyone knows the way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct support for QueryOver. I encourage you to create an item in the [issue tracker](http://issues.castleproject.org/issues/AR), then [fork the repository](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord) and implement it. I'd start by looking at the implementation of [ActiveRecordLinqBase](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/ActiveRecordLinqBase.cs), it should be similar. But instead of a separate class, you could just implement this in ActiveRecordBase. Then wrap it in ActiveRecordMediator to that it can also be used in classes that don't inherit ActiveRecordBase.

Comment: Nhibernate.Criterion.QueryOver has a static method "Of<T>", which can return an instance of QueryOver<T,T>.

Comment: @James : if it's static, where do you define what session it will run against?

Comment: `public class ActiveRecordMediator3<T> : ActiveRecordMediator where T : class
{
    public static IQueryOver<T, T>  GetExecutableQueryOver(QueryOver<T> queryOver)
    {
        var session = GetSessionFactoryHolder().CreateSession(typeof(T));

        return queryOver.GetExecutableQueryOver(session);
    }
}`

Comment: @James: nice, can you add it to `ActiveRecordMediator` and send a pull request? Also there should be some tests.

Comment: `QueryOver<T>.DetachedCriterion'`can return an `DetachedCriterion` instance, the method my previous comment talking about is not so necessary, I think.

Answer (score 3):

First, QueryOver.Of<T> return an instance of QueryOver<T, T>, then you build conditions with QueryOver API.

After that,  query.DetachedCriteria return the equivalent DetachedCriteria, which can be used with ActiveRecord gracefully.

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<PaidProduct>()
.Where(paid =>
       paid.Account.OrderNumber == orderNumber
       && paid.ProductDelivery.Product == product)
       .OrderBy(paid=>paid.ProductDelivery.DeliveredDate).Desc;
return ActiveRecordMediator<PaidProduct>.FindAll(query.DetachedCriteria);
```

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know that queryover could be converted to a detachedcriteria so easily.

Comment: any change to get this working with a Select statement, to change the return-type? Lets say I just want the productname, is this possible? I can't figure out a way to let the ActiveRecordMediator return anything besides a ActiveRecord-model, for example a string.